# How to Convert a Website Created in FrontPage to standard HTML

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser, frontpage

Does anyone know of an easy way to take the website created in MS Frontpage and convert it into working standard html without all of the goop that FP puts in there?

I've got a site that was created in FP which renders fine in IE (of course) but for which the links don't work in any of the other browsers. I've been brought into this after the fact so I'm already aware of all of the reasons why FP is to be avoided.

But now that we're at this point does anyone know of a less painful way out?

Here's the site if need be:

www.easeldoesit.net

Comment: Ouch, sounds like the short straw to me...

Comment: Frontpage!!...I thought it had it's place only in a web museum!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your code through [HTML TIDY](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) and/or the W3C's [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), and then fixing the problems that are identified. You'll have to do quite a bit of hand-coding to streamline your code the way you want it, but these tools should help make that process more efficient and less painful.

**Edit:** Even better, try the [Frontpage Code Cleaner](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/frontpage-code-cleaner.shtml) tool, or try following the steps outlined in this article: "[Cleaning up your FrontPage Code](http://accessfp.net/frontpage-2003/tutorials/cleaning-up-frontpage-code.htm)".

Comment: Thanks Krispy Kream,

Front Page Code Cleaner made it doable. Hats Off.

Answer (score 2):

I would try [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/).

Answer (score 0):

Code it yourself. (Sorry, I can't think of a better option.)

Also, I noticed from looking at the site that the reason that the links don't work is that they link to a local file. 
file:///C:%5CDocuments%20and%20Settings%5CAll%20Users%5CDocuments%5CMy%20Webs%5Cclasses.htm